# Multiple container for selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.141.59-yttrium on the same host EC2

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

can someone help me in understanding why multiple `selenium/standalone-chrome-debug` containers on the same host (EC2) are not working except 1.

I am starting my containers as

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 5900:5900 --shm-size 2g --net host --dns 127.0.0.1 --name image1 load-test:latest
docker run -d -p 4445:4444 -p 5901:5900 --shm-size 2g --net host --dns 127.0.0.1 --name image2 load-test:latest
docker run -d -p 4446:4444 -p 5902:5900 --shm-size 2g --net host --dns 127.0.0.1 --name image3 load-test:latest
```

and then

```
docker exec image1 java -jar -Dip=1.1.1.1 -DimageName=image1 -Ddebug=False perf-test.jar
docker exec image2 java -jar -Dip=1.1.1.1 -DimageName=image2 -Ddebug=False perf-test.jar
docker exec image3 java -jar -Dip=1.1.1.1 -DimageName=image3 -Ddebug=False perf-test.jar
```

but only the first image comes up and starts the test. Other images are showing a blank chrome screen and giving this error

```
screenshot failed, retrying timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000

[1577846494.939][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
[1577846494.939][WARNING]: screenshot failed, retrying timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
[1577846504.939][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
[1577846514.944][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
[1577846514.944][WARNING]: screenshot failed, retrying timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
[1577846524.944][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
```

Our code is very simple nothing fancy

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//driver.manage().window().maximize();
return driver;
```

But we are also doing this as soon as the user logs-in

```
    private void takeSnapshot( String filename) {

        try {

            TakesScreenshot screenshot = (TakesScreenshot) threadWebDriver.get();

            File source = screenshot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

            File target = new File(filename);

            FileUtils.copyFile(source, target);
        }
        catch( Exception e ) {

            logger.warn("takeSnapshot caught exception: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: At a guess, you're confusing it by sharing /dev/shm across all three docker images.  Why would you want to do this?

Comment: ah yes, I was thinking I copied the `--shm-size 2g` but I copied the other example. Updated my question but even when I use `--shm-size 2g`, I am still getting the same behavior.

Comment: Are you trying to start a new chrome browser in each of the three docker instances you run? I did not know one could run a instance of chrome inside a docker image...